# How to make a class library reference another class library that contains just an interface?

Tags: vb.net, interface, class-library

I have an interface `IMaths` which contains a single function ADD as follows. The name of this project is MyInterface which also becomes the default namespace. The code is as follows.

```
Class InterfaceHolder
    Interface IMaths
        Function ADD(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer
    End Interface
End Class
```

The other project is titled MyMathsLibrary (also a class library) which references MyInterface and ideally I would like to write something like the following:

```
Public Class MathOperations 
    Implements MyInterface.IMaths  'Getting error
End Class
```

But its not working. The error message is

> "Type Imaths is not defined"

Can someone pls tell me how to create a class library with an interface? And how can another class library reference that and implement the interface in the way shown above - that is without creating an object (note that I was not able to declare the Interface as shared)?

Comment: What exactly is the error? Always tell us the exact error message you receive when asking a question - it's a lot easier than us having to guess or work it out!

Comment: And why is the IMaths interface inside a class? That's a bit odd, and I would guess unnecessary - unless you have a very specific reason for doing so. Have you tried `Implements InterfaceHolder.IMaths`, though? or `Implements MyInterface.InterfaceHolder.IMaths`? Since the interface is inside the class, you'll need to reference the class before the compiler will know where to find it.

Comment: @ADyson have tried both, that is `Implements InterfaceHolder.IMaths` and  `Implements MyInterface.InterfaceHolder.IMaths`  but neither works. The error message is : "Type Imaths is not defined"

Comment: @ADyson I tried writing the Interface as it is, that the same thing excluding the Class & End Class statements. But got the exact same error. Thats why I put it in a class - but no particular reason behind that. I was just trying alternatives to see if they work or not.

Comment: Putting it into a class is only going to make it less accessible, not more. Can you reference other things from the MyInterface namespace in your MyMathsLibrary code without errors, or not?

Comment: @ADyson it seems I cant. There seems to be some problem with the referencing. But let me check it thoroughly and I shall come back

Comment: "what role does the word OBJECT play in the statement - Shared Function createMathsObject() As Object?"  All classes derive from Object, so it can be placed there and anything could be returned.  This is generally a bad idea, though!  It would be more correct to make it return MathOperations, or possibly put an INTERFACE name there and then you could return any instance of a class that implements that interface.

Comment: Don't change the post into a completely different question. It makes the earlier comments and answers nonsensical. If you have a new question, make a new post  about it. I've rolled back your change to restore what was there before. If you want to retrieve what you wrote in order to copy it to a new question you can get it from the question history at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69767164/revisions

Comment: @ADyson noted. Have reposted the question.

Comment: @Idle_Mind thank you for your comment. pls note that i have reposted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70031094/understanding-the-return-type-in-a-function

Comment: @Idle_Mind is there a way for me to move your comment to this new thread where I have reposted the question?

Answer (score 0):

You will get an error until you actually implement the interface.

```
Interface IMaths
    Function ADD(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer
End Interface

Public Class MathOperations
    Implements IMaths  'Getting error

    Public Function ADD(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer Implements IMaths.ADD
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function
End Class
```