# Understanding the return type in a function

Tags: vb.net

There are examples I have seen where the return type mentioned in the function declaration is different from the default return type mentioned in the Return statement present in the body of the function. I am trying to understand how this works. For that I have come up with the following hypothetical example:

I had defined a class library `MyMathsLibrary` as following:

```
Public Class MathOperations
       Public Function ADD(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer
           Return a + b
       End Function
End Class
```

Then I imported the above class Library into another class library named `FactoryMathsLibrary` as follows:

```
Imports MyMathsLibrary
Public Class Factory
    Shared Function createMathsObject() As Object
       Return New MathOperations()
    End Function
End Class
```

Finally, I write the following code piece:

```
Imports FactoryMathsLibrary
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim a, b As Integer
        Dim m As Object = Factory.createMathsObject()
        Console.WriteLine(m.GetType())'O/P: MyMathsLibrary.MathOperations
       
        Console.WriteLine("a + b = {0}", m.ADD(10, 5))
        Console.WriteLine("a - b = {0}", m.Minus(20, 7))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

### Question 1:

The function `createMathsObject` returns a reference which gets stored in the variable `m`. The output of the GetType command confirms that the reference that is returned points towards an instance of `MathOperations` class. So if that is the case what role does the word OBJECT play in the statement - `Shared Function createMathsObject() As Object`?

## Related question:

Suppose there is an interface with only the ADD function in it and the class `MathOperations` implements the interface. In this case the variable m can be both of the Interface type as well as OBJECT type. In both cases it should be able to store the references that `createMathsObject` returns. In such a case, the good practice seems to be to declare `m` of interface type. My question is, is this because we need to avoid late binding wherever possible or is there any other reason? One drawback of declaring `m` to be of interface type (which could be a justification behind declaring `m` to be Object type) is that we cannot access elements which are not defined in the interface - for example if we declare m as object type and the interface has only the ADD method defined it it, we cannot write something like `m.minus(a,b)`. Here MINUS should be assumed to be a function that calculates the difference between two values but is not a part of the Interface - rather its exclusive to the `MathOperations` class.

Comment: The first what you should do if you start learning VB.NET is to [set `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454552/what-do-option-strict-and-option-explicit-do) to `ON`  in your project and as default. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454552/what-do-option-strict-and-option-explicit-do Then `m.ADD` would not compile because you are returning `System.Object` not `MathOperations`. Every type instance is an `Object` because it is the base clase. But you have to cast that object to it'as real type if you want to use methods that don't exist in `Object`.

Comment: Should be `Shared Function createMathsObject() As MathOperations` really, then you won't need to cast it later in order to use the functions. But the factory method here adds no value if all it does is call the default constructor.

Comment: `My question is, is this because we need to avoid late binding wherever possible or is there any other reason`...maybe read about techniques such as Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control, where you program to an interface, so that if the concrete implementation of the class changes later, you don't need to recode lots of other references. e.g. if you have a data-storage class and you want to change it from a class which delivered file-based storage to one which delivers database storage, it's a lot easier to do that if you just re-implement the same interface methods...

Comment: ...and all the code which was using that class was actually using instances of the interface rather than the concrete class - because then you don't need to change any of the code which was using it. It also enables you to do things like build code libraries you distribute to others, and which - for example - might find it useful to be able to log debugging data. So instead of that library having its own logging functionality, it can just accept an instance of `ILogger` in its constructor, which then enables it to use whatever logging setup the host application is already using.

Comment: Interfaces and inheritance, and related concepts, is a big topic and it might be worth your while spending more some time reading a book, or studying some videos / blogs / tutorials etc to firm up your understanding, alongside asking specific questions.

Comment: When you try to assign a value of type `A` to an entity of type `B` there are two possible outcomes: an error, or a conversion.  Without `Option Strict On`, VB will always choose conversion, attempting it at runtime if necessary (which can result in an exception if the conversion isn't possible).